# Can I update another ParseUser data different by the on logged in?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to update a field from table 'User' of a `ParseUser` different by the one logged in.
The code below is not working and I was wondering if there is some impediment that does not allow to update other's user info.

```
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> userQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
    userQuery.whereMatches("objectId", "4mdsJKKgDJ");

    userQuery.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
            // I retreive the parseUser object correctly here
            int score = parseUser.getInt("score"); // I have added this column in User table with a default value of 0
            parseUser.put("score", score+1);
            parseUser.saveInBackground(); // nothing happens. the value is not updated
        }
    });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself to my question: you cannot update another user info, different by the one logged in.
Using:

```
  parseUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
     @Override
     public void done(ParseException e) {
           System.out.println("ParseException: "+ e);
     }
 });
```

revealed the problem:

```
com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot save a ParseUser that is not authenticated.
```

So I will need to use another table to keep this info.

Comment: You can do it in a cloud function with useMasterKey()

Comment: `useMasterKey() is only available in our JavaScript SDK` (https://www.parse.com/questions/using-master-key-with-android)  - this doesn't really help me

Comment: As I said, in a cloud function, where JS is used. This is the only way it can be done.